# How to fix failed redirects after login in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I added login to my site, everything works except one thing: if a user who is not logged in is not redirected to login.php, I tried several things please help me, Thanks.

process.php (login process):

```
    if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password && ("" !== $username || "" !== $password)){
    $_SESSION["users"] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    header("Location: https://**********/inde.php");
} else {
    header("Location: error.php");
}
```

logout.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['users'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['login'] = false;
header("location: https://**********/login.php");
exit();
```

On all pages of the website I added:

```
include("content/login_verif.php");
```

login_verif.php:

```
session_start();
if $_SESSION['login'] != true;
{
    header('Location: https://**********/login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put a safeguard in your home page. Check whether both `$_SESSION['users']` and `$_SESSION['login']` is set or not. If either of them is not set, then redirect the user to login page.

**login_verif.php**

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['users']) || !isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    // redirect the user to login page
    header('Location: https://ferapps.altervista.org/tia/content/login/login.php');
    exit();
}
```

and include this *login_verif.php* page in the following way,

```
require_once("content/login_verif.php");
```

And that's not how you should logout a user. You need to properly clear the cookies and destroy the sessions, so your *logout.php* page should be like this:

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['users']) || !isset($_SESSION['login'])){
        // redirect the user to login page
        header('Location: https://ferapps.altervista.org/tia/content/login/login.php');
        exit();
    }

    $_SESSION = array();
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
        setcookie(session_name(),'',time()-42000,'/');
    }
    session_destroy();

    // redirect the user to login page
    header('Location: https://ferapps.altervista.org/tia/content/login/login.php');
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents()
```

is used to output the contents of a file as a string.

You want

```
include("content/login_verif.php");
```

instead. And

```
if $_SESSION['login'] != true;
```

should be

```
if ($_SESSION['login'] != true)
```

Comment: Edited answer, check again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the incorrect use of "file_get_contents".

file_get_contents as explained at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php is a way to fetch the content of another file and return it in a string format.

If you wanna extend a file with another files code you should look into require and/or include.

For your current code, swap out

```
file_get_contents("content/login_verif.php");
```

For

```
require("content/login_verif.php");
```

**Information regarding include:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

**Information regarding require:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php